# Breakdown of Drug's Dosage weight (mg) to tablets

Tags: c#-4.0, recursion

I am writing a piece of code in c# to retreive number of tablets for a given dosage. For example, if a Dosage is 20 mg of DrugA (if DrugA comes in 10mg, 5mg and 2mg tablets) then the code would return (2). If Dosage is 15 then the code would return (1 & 1). If a dosage is 3 then Invalid Dosage message is returned. The code must use the highest denominations first i.e. 10mg tablets and then 5mg tablets for the remainder and so on. I am using recursive function (GetDispenseBreakdownForSingleDosage) to acheive the above functionality. My code is working fine for most of the scenarios that I tested. The one scenario that it is incorrectly returning Invalid Dosage is for 8mg dosage. The code should return (4) since 2mg tablets is a valid option. I have given my code below. My questions are:

1) Is there a better way of acheiving my objective than using my code.

2) What changes should I make to avoid the trap of 8mg as invalid dosage. It is returning it invalid because code divides 8 with 5 during second recursive call and remainder becomes 3, on third recursive call 3 is not divisible by 2 so code returns invalid dosage.

My code is given below:

```
public string GetDispenseBreakdown(PrescriptionsBLL Prescription, double[] IndexAndNonIndexDosageForBreakdown)
        {
            int[] NoOfTablets = new int[Prescription.SelectedDrug.PrescriptionsDrugWeights.Count];                        
            for (int Index = 1; Index <= IndexAndNonIndexDosageForBreakdown.Length; Index++)
            {
                GetDispenseBreakdownForSingleDosage(Prescription, ref NoOfTablets, IndexAndNonIndexDosageForBreakdown[(Index - 1)], Prescription.SelectedDrug.PrescriptionsDrugWeights[0].Weight, 1);//assuming that index 0 will always contain the highest weight i.e. if a drug has 2, 5, 10 as drug weights then index 0 should always contain 10 as we are sorting by Desc                
            }            
            return ConvertNumberOfTabletsIntoString(NoOfTablets);
        }
        public void GetDispenseBreakdownForSingleDosage(PrescriptionsBLL Prescription, ref int[] NoOfTablets, double Dosage, double Weight, int WeightCount)
        {            
            int LoopIteration;
            string TempLoopIteration = (Dosage / Weight).ToString();
            if (TempLoopIteration.Contains("."))
                LoopIteration = (int)Math.Floor(Dosage / Weight);
            else
                LoopIteration = int.Parse(TempLoopIteration);

            double TempDosage = Weight * LoopIteration;
            int WeightTablets = LoopIteration;
            double RemainingDosage = Math.Round((Dosage - TempDosage), 2);

            NoOfTablets[(WeightCount - 1)] = NoOfTablets[(WeightCount - 1)] + WeightTablets;

            if (WeightCount == Prescription.SelectedDrug.PrescriptionsDrugWeights.Count && RemainingDosage > 0.0)
            {
                NoOfTablets[0] = -99999;//Invalid Dosage
                return;
            }

            if (LoopIteration == 0 && Dosage > 0.0 && WeightCount == Prescription.SelectedDrug.PrescriptionsDrugWeights.Count)
            {
                NoOfTablets[0] = -99999;//Invalid Dosage
                return;
            }

            if (WeightCount == Prescription.SelectedDrug.PrescriptionsDrugWeights.Count)
                return;

            GetDispenseBreakdownForSingleDosage(Prescription, ref NoOfTablets, RemainingDosage, Prescription.SelectedDrug.PrescriptionsDrugWeights[WeightCount].Weight, ++WeightCount);            
        }
        public bool IsDosageValid(int[] NoOfTablets)
        {
            if (NoOfTablets[0] == -99999)
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }
        public string ConvertNumberOfTabletsIntoString(int[] NoOfTablets)
        {
            if (!IsDosageValid(NoOfTablets))
                return "Dosage is Invalid";
            string DispenseBreakDown = "(";
            int ItemsAdded = 0;
            for (int Count = 0; Count < NoOfTablets.Length; Count++)
            {
                if (NoOfTablets[Count] != 0)
                {
                    if (ItemsAdded > 0)
                        DispenseBreakDown += " & " + NoOfTablets[Count];
                    else
                        DispenseBreakDown += NoOfTablets[Count];
                    ItemsAdded = ItemsAdded + 1;
                }
            }
            DispenseBreakDown += ")";
            return DispenseBreakDown;
        }
```

Comment: Just for fun I tried it. Here's my solution: https://ideone.com/XXng3z

Comment: This is very simple and elegant solution to fullfil my needs, thanks. Please post it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple recursive method. Pass it the desired dosage and an empty list:

```
// Test if 2 floats are "equal", the difference between them
// is less than some predefined value (epsilon)
bool floatIsEqual(float f1, float f2)
{
    float epsilon = 0.001f;
    return Math.Abs(f1 - f2) <= epsilon;
}
static bool CalcDose(float desired, List<float> list)
{
    // Order of array is important. Larger values will be attempted first
    float[] sizes = new float[] { 8, 2, .4f, .2f };

    // This path isn't working, return
    if (desired < sizes[sizes.Length - 1])
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Try all combos
    for (int i = 0; i < sizes.Length; i++)
    {
        if (floatIsEqual(desired, sizes[i]))
        {
            // Final step: perfect match
            list.Add(sizes[i]);
            return true;
        }
        if (sizes[i] <= desired)
        {
            // Attempt recursive call
            if (true == CalcDose( desired - sizes[i], list))
            {
                // Success
                list.Add(sizes[i]);
                return true;
            }
            else break;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I've found that this function gets into an infinite loop if I set my desired to 9.3 (I am using double instead of int) and set following four sizes: 8, 2, 0.4 and 0.2. It should return invalid dosage but it gets into an infinite loop instead. Do you have a workaround for that?

Comment: Looks like a floating point error. I fixed that and made a few other fixes. Try it now.

Comment: Thanks for the update, it passes the test for 9.3 and returns 'Invalid Dosage' but it is now failing other tests i.e desired dosage 13, 15, 17 (odd numbers may be??) for following sizes: 8, 2, 0.4, 0.2. It passes test for 20, 8, 12 etc for the same 4 sizes. It is also failing test for desired dosage of 8 and 13 for following 3 sizes: 10, 5 and 2. It passes tests for desired dosage of 14, 15, 17, 20, 12 etc for the same 3 sizes. Any idea??

Comment: I'm fairly certain these errors are caused by floating point rounding errors. Try this: change back to ints. Convert all values to int by multiplying by some power of 10 (ex: 100). Then run calculation. Ex: sizes = 800, 200, 40, 20 and dosage = 1300. Consider using Fixed Point math.

Comment: I've updated the ide example to use fixed point. I've run all your cases and they work: https://ideone.com/XXng3z

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a version of the same logic required for coin change.

This site goes through that logic:
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-7-coin-change/

You will also need to make a few adjustments:

1. You'll need to get back the possible results and accept the one that has highest number of larger pills.
2. You'll need to handle the possibility of no "correct change".

Comment: I didn't try this option because Johnny Mopp's solution was very simple and I only needed to replace console.writeline with one line of my own code.Thanks for the help anyways and plus 1 for your effort.